# Разделение элементов массива на группы, код Шеннона-Фано

Tags: c++, c

Реализовываю алгоритм Шеннона-Фано на C (Да, я знаю, что всё уже давно реализовано). На данный момент имеется массив символов, обнаруженных в сообщении, и отсортированный массив частот их появления. Теперь нужно разбить массив частот поровну, чтобы в первой группе сумма частот была максимальна равна сумме частот во второй группе. Символам из первой группы присваиваются нули в их кодах, символам из второй группы - единицы. Ну, то есть прибавляем 0 или 1 и сдвигаем влево.
Подскажите, как алгоритмизировать разбиение групп? Дальше разбиения первых двух групп мыслей нету.

Answer (score 1):

Вот эта функция разобьет массив на группы и выведет все коды соответствующих символов:

```
void SearchTree (char *symbols, int *freq, string &branch, string &fullBranch, int start, int end)
{
double dS=0;
int i,m,S=0;
string cBranch="";

cBranch=fullBranch+branch;
if (start==end)
{
    cout << symbols[start] << " --- " << cBranch;
    return;
}
for (i=start;i<=end;i++)
    dS+=freq[i];
dS/=2.;
i=start+1;
S+=freq[start];
while (fabs(dS-(S+freq[i]))<fabs(dS-S) && (i<end))
{
    S+=freq[i];
    i++;
}
string zero="0";
string one="1";
SearchTree(symbols,freq,one,cBranch,start,i-1);
SearchTree(symbols,freq,zero,cBranch,i,end);
}
```

Входные данные - Отсортированный массив символов длины n, Отсортированный массив частот появления символов длины n, номер группы (ветви, пустая строка при первом вызове), История поворотов по ветвям (Пустая строка при первом вызове), начальный и конечный номер элемента массива символов.